# What is the importance of the folded napkin in the empty tomb?

Tags: john, jesus

What is the importance of the folded napkin n the empty tomb?

> And the napkin, that was about his head, not lying with the linen clothes, but wrapped together in a place by itself. John 20:7. [**TR**](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/43020007).

Comment: One garment was removed in crucifixion and remained intact (not divided, but cast lots for). After resurrection there are two garments - one for the head, one for the body. And John saw, and believed.I have edited and added the text. Please feel free to revert if you wish.

Comment: Related to https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/9187/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-face-cloth-rolled-up-in-john-207

Comment: John appears to have made the point that Jesus arose through the garments leaving them laying in place as when he was dead.

Comment: cf. Job 40:13, Psalms 132:10